# Chart title with useHTML doesn't format properly on first load

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, electron

When I am creating a new chart, I am using an image for the title like this:

```
title: {
    useHTML: true,
    text: "<img src='https://abload.de/img/logo0tjrw.png' alt='' />",
    align: 'left'
    },
```

When I first run the program, the title is not aligned properly unless the window gets resized, then the title snaps into the correct position.

First load:
[image]

Second load or browser window resized:
[image]

Here is a jsfiddle as an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/7e2wbshm/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For proper image positioning, ensure to specify its size:

```
  title: {
    useHTML: true,
    text: "<img src='https://abload.de/img/logo0tjrw.png' height='100'/>",
    align: 'left',
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/83oedsjg/

As an additional tip: For optimal display on Retina monitors, consider setting your image resolution to twice the size while halving the dimensions. This adjustment ensures optimal clarity and sharpness.

For further details, check out: https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/12/27/picture-perfect-images-with-the-modern-element/#h3-7f5bfcb8aa9a0

Comment: This is better, but if you set the align to center, and open the chart in a new window the image is rendered to far to the right: https://jsfiddle.net/u3sm1vro/ 
So after a reload the image is actually centered on the chart vertically and horizontally

Comment: If you set the height and width to the actual size of the image, it renders properly. Thanks for the help !